# Javascript: Can't control parent of descendant nodes

Tags: javascript, parent, controlling

I'm creating elements (level 1) dynamically which in turn create elements (level 2) themselves. However, the children of level 2 elements have "body" as their parent.

In the HTML code below, the content if spotAd2 is created by my function createNode(). It's a Google Ad Sense tag. However, the Google Ad Sense tag create elements that went directly under "body". I need them to by under tnDiv1.

```
function createNode( t, // type.
                     tn, // if type is element, tag name.
                     a, // if type is element, attributes.
                     v, // node value or text content
                     p, // parent
                     f ) // whether to make dist the first child or not.
{
  n = null;

  switch( t )
  {
    case "element":
      n = document.createElement( tn );

      if( a )
      {
        for( k in a )
        {
          n.setAttribute( k, a[ k ] );
        }
      }
    break;

    case "text":
    case "cdata_section":
    case "comment":
      n = document.createTextNode(v);
    break;
  }
  if ( p )
  {
  if( f )
  {
    p.insertBefore( n, p.firstChild );
  }
  else
  {
    p.appendChild( n );
  }
}
  return n;
}

spotAd2 = document.getElementById("spotAd2");
n1 = createNode("element", "div", {"id":"tnDiv1"}, "\n" , spotAd2, true);
n2 = createNode("element", "script", {"type":"text\/javascript"}, "\n" , n1, false);
n3 = createNode("comment", "", null, "\n" +
"google_ad_client = \"pub-0321943928525350\";\n" +
"/* 728x90 (main top) */\n" +
"google_ad_slot = \"2783893649\";\n" +
"google_ad_width = 728;\n" +
"google_ad_height = 90;\n" +
"//\n" , n2, false);
n4 = createNode("element", "script", {"type":"text\/javascript","src":"http:\/\/pagead2.googlesyndication.com\/pagead\/show_ads.js"}, "\n" , n1, false);
```

--- Result:

```
<body>

<table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" border="1">
<tbody><tr>
<td>Oel ngati kemeie</td>
<td>Kamakto niwin</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>The ad:</td>
<td>

  <div id="spotAd2">
    <!-- Created by createNode() -->
    <div id="tnDiv1">
      <script type="text/javascript">
        google_ad_client = "pub-0321943928525350";
        /* 728x90 (main top) */
        google_ad_slot = "2783893649";
        google_ad_width = 728;
        google_ad_height = 90;
      </script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js"></script>
    </div>
    <!-- Created by createNode() -->
  </div>

</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>txopu ra'a tsi, tsamsiyu</td>
<td>teyrakup skxawng</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>

<!-- Created by adsense tag, need these to be under tnDiv1 -->
<script src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/expansion_embed.js"></script>
<script src="http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/test_domain.js"></script>
<script>google_protectAndRun("ads_core.google_render_ad", google_handleError, google_render_ad);</script>
<ins style="border: medium none ; margin: 0pt; padding: 0pt; display: inline-table; height: 90px; position: relative; visibility: visible; width: 728px;">
  <ins style="border: medium none ; margin: 0pt; padding: 0pt; display: block; height: 90px; position: relative; visibility: visible; width: 728px;">
    <iframe width="728" scrolling="no" height="90" frameborder="0" vspace="0" style="left: 0pt; position: absolute; top: 0pt;" src="http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/ads?client=ca-pub-0321943928525350&amp;output=html&amp;h=90&amp;slotname=2783893649&amp;w=728&amp;lmt=1273708979&amp;flash=10.0.45&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fkenshin.katanatechworks.com%2Ftest%2FadsBrowserSide.php&amp;dt=1273708980294&amp;shv=r20100422&amp;correlator=1273708980298&amp;frm=0&amp;ga_vid=695691836.1273708981&amp;ga_sid=1273708981&amp;ga_hid=1961182006&amp;ga_fc=0&amp;u_tz=480&amp;u_his=2&amp;u_java=1&amp;u_h=1080&amp;u_w=1920&amp;u_ah=1052&amp;u_aw=1920&amp;u_cd=24&amp;u_nplug=5&amp;u_nmime=38&amp;biw=1394&amp;bih=324&amp;fu=0&amp;ifi=1&amp;dtd=955&amp;xpc=Jl67G4xiq6&amp;p=http%3A//kenshin.katanatechworks.com" name="google_ads_frame" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" id="google_ads_frame1" hspace="0" allowtransparency="true">
    </iframe>
  </ins>
</ins>
<!-- Created by adsense tag, need these to be under tnDiv1 -->
</body>
```

Comment: _Please_ use meaningful variable names.

Comment: This isn't a real question at all. You need to show us where there is a problem, and not just dump code.

Comment: I am very sorry if this is not properly formatted (my first time here).

I'll create a new question and format it properly.

Comment: Just update this question, no need to create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after much needed sleep (been awake for almost 24 hours) my head cleared up and was able to analyze the problem better (with some helpful inputs from my colleagues).

I realized that the culprit is document.write() and should have asked something like this:

[JavaScript - controlling the insertion point for document.write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536970/javascript-controlling-the-insertion-point-for-document-write)

Which lead me to a whole lot of solutions.

I then came up with this prototype:

```
document.write = function(str)
{
    div = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml","div");
    div.innerHTML = str;

    var nodes = div.childNodes;
    while ( nodes.length )
    {
        document.getElementById("spotAd2").appendChild( nodes[0] );
    }
};
```

Voila! The AdSense ad showed up where I want it to be.

With a little bit of refinement, I can turn this into a generic solution.