# Is there a way to intercept `document.write`?

Tags: javascript, document.write, advertisement-server

I am trying to lazy load some adserver code...

On the page I have this at the moment:

```
<div class="ad">
    <span>pos_1</span>
</div>
```

I then go through and pull out all of the ads that should be on the page, call their javascript include file and it gives me this lovely mess:

```
function do_ad(pos){
    switch(pos){
        case 'pos_1':
            document.write('first ad text');
            document.write('first ad more text');
            //and so on for many many lines
            break;
        case 'pos_2':
            document.write('second ad text');
            document.write('second ad more text');
            //and so on for many many lines
            break;
    }
}
```

I then want to replace the span with the results of the `document.write` ad call.

Is there a way to get it to return the string that would have been written to the page?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript - controlling the insertion point for document.write](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536970/javascript-controlling-the-insertion-point-for-document-write)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't see why you can't overwrite the `document.write` function:

```
document.old_write = document.write;

document.write = function (str) {
    // lalala
};
```

See here: http://www.jsfiddle.net/N9hXy/

Comment: Thanks! Now I have to deal with other failings in their script... sigh

Comment: Alas... this didn't quite work the way I wanted it to... because the ad server is three levels deep: `document.write('<script>document.write('<script>document.write('ad text')</script>'))</script>';`. It worked fine for a single depth though.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.write = function(str) {
    window.buf += str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The do_ad(pos) function must be called somewhere. Why not where the ad should be displayed?

```
<div class="ad">
    <script>do_ad("pos_1");</script>
</div>
```