# Is it possible to use external .js file partly?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a puzzling situation (puzzling for me at least).

There is an external file "file.js" which is created by an external website:

http://external-website.com/file.js

it has this code inside of it:

```
var sText= "dynamic value here";
document.write(sText);
```

So basically this website recreates this file every N minutes to provide people with means to incorporate the values from this js file in their website using

```
<script src="http://external-website.com/file.js"></script>
```

BUT

I need the variable sText only. I don't want this script to do `document.write(sText)` because this messes up my DOM (if I understand correctly). Ideally I'd be happy if this file had one line `var sText= "dynamic value here";`

Is there a way to use this JS but don't let it do the `document.write` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript - controlling the insertion point for document.write](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536970/javascript-controlling-the-insertion-point-for-document-write)

Comment: The dupe has some incorrect or useless answers, but those by Eric, Noah, gregers, and Karl might be useful.

Comment: A hacky solution would be to temporarily replace `document.write` with a custom callback.

Comment: If you really need just one variable from file, you can get script text via ajax and parse out data you need; also you can do it in server "proxy" script. Partial run of script written not by you looks almost impossible. @Blender advice also looks good.

Comment: @Tommi: AJAX requests might not work due to the same-origin policy.

Comment: Yep, and I noted server-side solution because of it.

Comment: @Tommi - as you already noted - same-origin policy doesn't let me do that.

Comment: @Blender - any link to read up on that trick?:

Comment: @YuraAntonov: Seems like someone already implemented it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10977220/464744

Comment: Looks complicated. Why not just set document._write = document.write; document.write = function() {}; before file.js load and restore  document.write = document._write; delete document._write; after script load complete?

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the script into an AST and then extract the string from the variable definition node. See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Bx36/20/).

First you define the external script file like this:

```
<script type="text/x-ignore_me" src="http://external-website.com/file.js"></script>
```

The `text/x-ignore_me` type should not be recognized by your browser. Thus, the browser ignores that script. Now we can access the content of the script and parse it with the [Uglify.js](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2) parser.

```
var code = $("script[type='text/x-ignore_me']").text();
var ast = UglifyJS.parse(code);
var sTextContent = ast.body[0].definitions[0].value.print_to_string();
alert( sTextContent );
```

You find the content of `sText` (which is "dynamic value here" in your example) in the `sTextContent` variable.

As a reference, you find the Uglify.js parser documentation [here](http://lisperator.net/uglifyjs/parser).

Answer (score 0):

When the `document.write` gets executed, what you can do is through fireBug or any other similar program, detect the class or ID that is rendered by the Div generated through the `document.write`

You have to override that class or ID of the rendered div and just make it to `display:none;`
 or `display:none !important;` in your style file.
I think this will solve your purpose without touching the JS file.