# Jquery script is not loaded, on appendChild

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am loading my script files dynamically using this code,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var newscript = document.createElement('script');
  newscript.type = 'text/javascript';
  newscript.src = '../static/js/jquery.js';
  document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0].appendChild(newscript);

  var newscript = document.createElement('script');
  newscript.type = 'text/javascript';
  newscript.src = '../static/js/report_app.js';
  document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0].appendChild(newscript);

</script>
```

It throws error as,

```
Reference error: $ is not defined
```

in `report_app.js`.

I thought, `jquery.js` script must be loaded into the DOM when the next file, `report_app.js` is being parsed.

But the error shows, `jquery.js` is not executed. How to ensure one script file is loaded before running the next one?

Comment: Where and when you use $ ?

Comment: This way, scripts are loaded asynchronously, use the jQuery script tag onload event to append the second one. And please avoid using same variable name twice

Comment: @OlegYudovich, $ is used inside report_app.js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because the script is added asynchronously, you can use the onload callback

```
function addScript(path, callback) {
    var newscript = document.createElement('script');
    newscript.type = 'text/javascript';
    newscript.src = path;
    newscript.onload = callback;
    document.body.appendChild(newscript);

}

addScript('http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.js', function () {
    addScript('../static/js/report_app.js');
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/0nchfyof/)